# jQuery broken when I change wordpress permalinks away from Default

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Help!!

I am using Javascript on the following page...  it should output a message below the submit botton when the sumbit button is clicked (the button passes the form to a .php file using jQuery and updates a database - the php then echos "thank you - we will contact you shortly"...

http://make-your-offer.com/private_beta.php

When I have permalinks set to Default - this works

When I have them set to anything else - it doesn't work

I've tried firebug but I am useless in figuring out what to do in this case!!

code here

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform2").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name2: "required",
            email2: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name2: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email2: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('/process3.php', $("#myform2").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The "process3.php" still updates the database when permalinks are at a setting which is not default - however the div id = "results" div is not updated

When permalinks are set to default - the results div does get updated...

i.e. the following bit of code

```
$('#results').html(data);
```

is not changing the webpage..   do I need to change the # to the file path of the webpage? i.e. (but the page isn't results.php...  the results div is on the page private_beta.php ..  so I do not know how to change this

```
$('/results').html(data);
```

Grrr it's driving me bonkers...

Cheers

Comment: I have updated the code above

Comment: How the `data` return from the server looks like, I bet the problem is there, debug it.

Comment: the `data` bit works normally though and it will be udpated if I have permalinks turned off.. I suspect a path issue (i.e. it cannot find the results div.. )?

Answer (score 0):

When I am using your site I currently get the following HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2012 08:35:45 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Pingback: http://make-your-offer.com/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: bp-message=deleted; expires=Tue, 01-Feb-2011 08:35:44 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: bp-message-type=deleted; expires=Tue, 01-Feb-2011 08:35:44 GMT; path=/
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Feb 2012 08:35:45 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=75
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

61
<font color='#008040'><b>Thank you for expressing interest - we will be in touch soon.</b></font>
0
```

Note the 404 Not Found at the top. If you set the permalink setting to default I'm pretty sure this would be something nicer (**Edit:** 200 OK is returned when permalinks are default). We'd probably need to see your PHP for handling this request  to debug it better.

Finding the target div is not the problem - this isn't affected by your link paths. Its the fact that your AJAX gets a negative response back, which means it won't run the callback.

**Edit:** I think this has something to do with it rewriting relative URLs when using custom permalinks, but I'm not completely sure. Try setting the post URL to `'http://make-your-offer.com/process3.php'`  and see if that works better. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440148/wordpress-permalinks) on how to create absolute links within WordPress (if this is what causes the problem to begin with).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760538/ajax-call-to-php-script-returns-404-error) might also be a relevant solution. I think that restructuring the `$.post` to use the `complete` callback could work in your case, but try simply running

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK')
```

In your process3.php before any other output is printed. This might do the trick, and would be the cleanest override.

**However**, this doesn't explain why the problem occurs, which I'm very curious about. It's probably some sort of protection against weird requests with rewritten URLs, but I really can't say for sure.

Comment: my PHP for handling the request in the simplest form echo's out a message - which is shown above ..   am I missing something in my .php ??

Comment: Returns 200 OK header which is a lot better. Updated my answer a bit with something to try.

Comment: Thanks Anders - I will have to try this when I get home from work. I do not have FTP access at work to change my files. However - given the php does actually process the database update (but just doesn't update the target div) - are you sure the above would work?

Comment: I'm absolutely not sure! :) This is why I would like to see the content of process3.php. But if you turn back on the faulty permalinks I can keep on looking for a solution.

Comment: the contents of process3.php are just something as simple as:  echo "Thank you for expressing interest - we will be in touch soon" prior to that is just updates a database with the form items passed to it..   (so  $sql = "INSERT into private_beta (name, email) = name, emal)..  that's all that is in there... faulty permalinks are turned back on

Comment: obviously my syntax isn't as bad as above - so it does actually update the database table fine!!

Comment: I've added a bunch of suggestions now, looking forward to understanding why this happens.

Comment: Thanks - me too! I don't understand what you mean here though restructuring the `$.post` to use the `complete`

Comment: When you use the callback in $.post it uses the "success" callback, which only gets fired if the request returns a 200 OK. If you use the "complete" callback instead, this would fire even if you are returned a 404 Not Found. However I'm not sure the complete callback can access your returned data, so it might not work perfeclty. Thus it's better to use the header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK') solution if it works.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give this a go tonight and report back

Comment: weird...  I changed the include(wp-blog-header) to be require(wp-config) and some other fields...  and it appears to have sorted it...  I did this because my final file had require(wp-config).. and I got a "headers have already been sent" message... so I removed the header(HTTP/1.1 200 OK) and it appears to be working fine now... hmmm  but ... hmmmm I'm very confused

Comment: Ahhh, the wonderous magic of computers. :) I honestly have no idea what the root of the problem is. Possibly you'd get better help from asking at the http://wordpress.org/support/ forums - they are very active and helpful.